# Do there exist any cuboids, five of whose seven distinct inter-vertex lengths are integers and the product of whose other two is also an integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory

There don’t seem to be any small ones. Perfect cuboids would be examples, so a proof that no examples exist that are not perfect cuboids would also be very interesting.

Comment: The perfect cuboid problem is hard enough, a different sounding problem is unlikely to be easier. Indeed, the (non) existence of perfect cuboids is related to the Bombieri-Lang conjecture, so a proof of non-existence (or even just finitely many) perfect cuboids would amount to proving a case of Bombieri-Lang, which would be a huge accomplishment.